# Dealing with CAPTCHA when calling API via requests

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to automate the calls of this API but it shows me this error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError (" Expecting value ", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

```
import requests

result = requests.get('https://api.freebinchecker.com/bin/371241')
print(result.status_code)

data = json.loads(result.content.decode('utf-8'))
print(data)
```

I have modified the code and now it shows me this.

In the web interface, ask for a captcha validity. How do I validate the captcha in the get function?

```
import requests

result = requests.get('https://api.freebinchecker.com/bin/371241')

encoded_response = json.dumps(result.text)
output = json.loads(encoded_response)
print(output)
```

Comment: Opening the URL in my browser I'm greeted with captcha. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is the problem.
I have updated the code.

Comment: The point of captcha is that it prevents automated requests. Maybe contacting the page owner/administrator and ask how to access the API programmatically.

Comment: Is there any reason that a url meant for API calls requires a captcha? The only thing I can think of is that if you register and use some authentication the captcha will be skipped

Comment: Did this ever get solved. I am running into the same problem